# How to pass Variable from list by button press

Tags: php, html, file

My goal is to read a directory, add items to a list, add individual buttons to delete a file a then add code to delete the selected file. The deleting is not a problem but passing the file is.

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php

 if ($handle = opendir('userStorage/Storage1')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
      {
            $filelocation = "userStorage/Storage1/$file";
            $thelist .= '<p1>'.$file.'</p1><form method="post">
            <button>Download</button>
            <button type="submit" name="delete'.$file.'" value="Submit" >Delete</button><br></form>';
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }       
?>

<?php
if($_POST["delete'.$file.'"] == "Submit" ) {
    
        echo "File to be deleted: $file";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: What do you expect to catch with `$_POST["delete'.$file.'"]`? That's just one value, while you build your table in a loop, with `n` different values. You need to restructure your HTML. How are you triggering the delete operation? Is it a regular form submission or AJAX?

Comment: Please specify the problem you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    unlink(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_POST['file']);
}

if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['file']);
}

$files = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__), ['..', '.']);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo "
        <p>{$file}</p>
        <form action='' method='POST'>
            <input type='hidden' name='file' value='{$file}'>
            <input type='submit' name='download' value='Download'>
            <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>
        </form>
    ";
}
```

Comment: you just need to add an input of type hidden and give it a name of $file and then you will be able to to get the value with $_POST

Comment: Hi, this worked perfect, thank you, congratulations on your first answer!

Comment: Thank you
glad to see that its helped you